# Metodo GET en .NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy desarrollando en .NET MVC pero el metodo GET em devuelve un error, probè como POST y funciona normal

probè usando `[HttpGet]` pero no pasa nada

```
    public ActionResult Hola(){
        return Json("Hola Mundo");
    }

    public JsonResult Lista(){
        List<contacto> ls = new List<contacto>();
        Conecta cn = new Conecta();
        MySqlDataReader reader = null;
        MySqlConnection conn = cn.ConexionMySQL();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM contacto", conn);

        try{
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read()){
                ls.Add(new contacto(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2)));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex){

        }

        return Json(ls);
    }
```

si los llamo mediante POST funciona normal, me devuelve la cadena o vista, pero por el mètodo GET e incluso puesto directamente en la URL solo me devuelve este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por seguridad la recomendación es que si no es autenticado el request en tu app, utilices POST para este tipo de devoluciones de JSON. Por eso esta "bloqueado por default", que se desbloquea como te comenta @Alan en la respuesta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando haces el return en tu controller debes establecer en `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` de esta manera:

```
return Json(ls,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

MVC deshabilita por defecto que puedas hacer un get y obtener esta información, la finalidad es proteger el acceso a datos por parte de terceros. (si te fijas en el error te lo informa).